# iPhone App Statistics - Log Random Number

Tags: iphone, analytics

Is there any way I could gather specific information from users who use my app?

For example, if I have a random number generate between 0 and 1,000, how can I find the most common generated number?

Would I use Flurry Analytics for this? If so, maybe I don't quite understand their website Interface with how events are logged. Could someone help explain?

Edit: More accurate title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below is an example of how you would log (for example) random numbers generated within your app.  Basically you send a `logEvent:withParameters:` message to the `FlurryAPI` class.  The logEvent parameter is an arbitrary name you give the event, and the parameters is a NSDictionary of name/value pairs you want to track for the event.  You can then see the recorded events with the data in the Flurry analytics reporting.

```
int rnd = arc4random() % 1000;

// use Flurry Analytics to record random number generated event 
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd], @"RandomNumber", nil];
[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"RandomNumberGenerated" withParameters:dictionary];
```

You can find more information about using Flurry Analytics to track events in their [Getting Started page](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Events).